# GitLab CI implementation of ZAP with Selenium

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, gitlab, zap, remotewebdriver

I have been trying to get ZAP running in the Gitlab CI pipeline but with no luck. Even though it works fine in my local machine on ChromeDriver , when i try interacting with Remote WebDriver while running on the Gitlab Shared Runner , i cant seem to access ZAP by doing something like driver.get("http://localhost:8080");

From the gitlab logs though , i can see that it says that :
ZAP is now listening on localhost:8080 once the ZAP-daemon gets launched as part of the commands given in gitlab-ci.yml file

Appreciate any help to understand what I am might be doing wrong here.

Please find the Test Code and the gitlab ci yml file below that I am using to run the test.

Test Code:

```
  ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore- certificate-errors");

  Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
  proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8080").setSslProxy("localhost:8080");


  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS,true);
  capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);


  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://selenium_chrome:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
  driver.get("http://localhost:8080");
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  String zapHeadingText = driver.getTitle();
  Assert.assertEquals(zapHeadingText,"ZAP API UI");
```

GitLab CI Yml File:

image: maven:latest
variables:
MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
cache:
paths:
- .m2/repository/
- target/
stages:

- Test
  Security_Test:
  stage: Test
  script:

  - mvn clean install
    services:
  - name: owasp/zap2docker-stable
    alias: zap
    entrypoint: ["zap.sh","-daemon", "-port", "8080", "-host", "localhost", "-config", "api.disablekey=true", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.name=.*", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.regex=true"]
  - name: selenium/standalone-chrome
    alias: selenium_chrome

Answer (score 0):

In ZAP we use the Chrome option `--ignore-certificate-errors` so it might be worth trying that. FYI the code is in https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/master/addOns/selenium/src/main/java/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/selenium/ExtensionSelenium.java so you might spot other things we do.

Comment: Thanks for replying Simon :), however even after trying all chrome options in the github page shared i am still getting connection refused with ZAP in RemoteWebDriver , when i am trying to run it in the Gitlab shared runners, it works perfectly fine in ChromeDriver in my local machine , would you know if there are any restrictions on running ZAP with RemoteWebDriver, in case if you had any examples that would be great.

Comment: Is selenium running on a different machine to ZAP? If so ZAP will probably need to listen on 0.0.0.0 and you'll need to configure it to accept remote connections as per https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-can-i-connect-to-zap-remotely/

Comment: Hi Simon. No Selenium and ZAP are both running in the same machine , and i am running them as docker containers as per the gitlab ci.yml file. Also I tried changing the host to 0.0.0.0 as you had mentioned and also had provided the remote connection details in the gitlab ci yml file as mentioned in my code sample above.  I also tried to run it directly using ChromeDriver instead of RemoteWebDriver and that also failed for the same reason. Hence am a bit lost on how to run Zap with Selenium on Gitlab CI at the moment.